# How to omit empty curly brackets, when encoding empty nested structs in Swift?

Tags: json, swift, encoding, nested

I am trying to create a nested Codable struct as part of a PATCH request object that I will be sending to a RESTful API.  I am using optionals for all properties, and I am initializing each of the nested structures. When encoding, the optionals are correctly omitted in the JSON object but the initialized empty nested structures are represented by "{}". Example:

```
struct RequestData: Codable {
    var id : String?
    var created : String?
    var name : String?
    var params = Parameters()
    
    struct Parameters: Codable{
        var token: String?
        var mode: Int?
        var uid: String?
    }
}
```

If I create a new `RequestData` and change for example the `token`, I get:

```
var test = RequestData()
test.params.token = "1234567890"
enc = try? JSONEncoder().encode(test)
```

Result: *{"params":{"token":"1234567890"}}*

If I do the same but don't change a property of the nested srtuct, I get a set of curly brackets:

```
var test = RequestData()
test.name = "John, Deere"
enc = try? JSONEncoder().encode(test)
```

Result: *{"name":"John, Deere","params":{}}*

Is there a way that I can force the JSONEncoder to omit the empty curly brackets in the final JSON?

Comment: Without the `{}`, it would be invalid JSON. Can you show the desired output?

Comment: The desired output would be: {"name":"John, Deere"}

Comment: Both answers should work for you then.

Comment: All you need to do is to declare your `params` property optional as well and don't initialize a new object by default.

Comment: This doesn't work, as the nested structure stays uninitialized and there is no instance to hold the value in teh parent struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default it will be `{}` because params **always** has a value.

But you can write you custom implementation of the encoder to select when you want to add `params` or not:

```
struct RequestData: Codable {
    var id : String?
    var created : String?
    var name : String?
    var params = Parameters()
    
    struct Parameters: Codable{
        var token: String?
        var mode: Int?
        var uid: String?
        
        func isDefined() -> Bool {
            return token != nil || mode != nil || uid != nil
        }
    }
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encodeIfPresent(id, forKey: .id)
        try container.encodeIfPresent(created, forKey: .created)
        try container.encodeIfPresent(name, forKey: .name)
        if params.isDefined() {
            try container.encode(params, forKey: .params)
        }
    }
}
```

`func encode(to encoder: Encoder)` is part of the [Encodable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/encodable/2893603-encode) protocol, by using our own implementation, you can modify the default behavior.

Comment: No need to check if a value is not equal to nil. There is a method exactly for this purpose for every Codable type that it is optional and one for optional generic types. You can simply use `encodeIfPresent` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/keyedencodingcontainer

Comment: @LeoDabus you are right, much better, I wasn't aware of `encodeIfPresent`

Comment: This is great; super thx! Using ```encodeIfPresent``` and checking if the nested struct is empty did the trick. I am wondering if there is a more elegant way to find out if the struct is empty, than probing each one of the properties.

Comment: @jiko you can extend Encodable protocol and create a generic method to check if the struct is an empty dictionary `extension Encodable {`
    `func isEmptydictionary(using encoder: JSONEncoder = .init()) throws -> Bool {` `(try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: encoder.encode(self)) as? [String: Any])?.isEmpty == true` `}` `}`

Comment: then you can use `if try !params.isEmptydictionary() {
    try container.encode(params, forKey: .params)
}`  in your decoder

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you're getting empty braces is because you've initialized `param's` value while `RequestData` instance creation,

```
var params = Parameters()
```

Instead declare `params` as `Optional` like,

```
var params: Parameters?
```

Now, you can create the instances like,

```
var test = RequestData()
test.name = "John, Deere"
var params = Parameters()
params.token = "1234567890"
test.params = params
```